# Segmentation Error in std::string

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdstring

I am getting an odd segmentation error on these lines of code.

```
OutputHandler(std::string const& path) throw(std::exception);

MyClass::MyClass() 
: basepath(boost::filesystem::canonical("./").string() + "/"),
outputHandler(basepath + "log.log") {} // Error traces back to this line (line 11)
```

The segmentation error:

```
#0  0x00007ffff6fd512b in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x0000000000423bd7 in std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > (__lhs=..., __rhs=0x4659a1 "log.log")
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2405
#2  0x0000000000414466 in MyClass::MyClass (this=0x7fffffffd6f0) at ./source/MyClass.cpp:11
#3  0x0000000000464a28 in main () at ./source/main.cpp:10
```

What is causing this error and how do I fix it? I am guessing something is going wrong when converting the `basepath + "log.log"` to a `std::string`?

Comment: Your member variable `basepath`, is it by any chance a reference? (Accidentially, of course)

Comment: I never stress enough that _"questions concerning problems with code you've written must [...] include valid code to reproduce it"_.

Comment: `MyClass::basepath` is a simple `std::string` declared as ` std::string basepath;` inside the class declaration.

Comment: Next Q: In the class definition, does `basepath` stand before or after `outputHandler`? (And do you have warnings enabled?)

Comment: @DanielFrey Warnings are off, Mark's answer solved it for me. Thanks for all your help. I really thought the problem would have something to do with the string construction. DX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of initialization of member variables is the order they're declared in the class definition, not the order they're listed in the initializer. The `basepath` string is probably not initialized yet.